# Default parameter values in r's gstat idw?

Tags: r, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

In r, gstat has an Inverse distance weighted (IDW) interpolation method.

Does anyone know what the default values of nmin, nmax and maxdist are?

Comment: You could improve this question by adding some sample code to show what function you are using. You should also always do some basic checks of the help for functions before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help file:

```
?gstat::idw

nmin = 0
nmax = Inf
maxdist = Inf
```

Comment: Why link to the raw Rd file in the github repo when you can get the answer from R's help system with `?idw` ?

Comment: @Spacedman that would make more sense... Answer updated.